The physical image is not observe by Hololens 2 using Vuforia for Image tracking
I have problem to use Vuforia for image tracking. So I explained what I did in detail as follows:
These steps are taken to use Vuforia for image tracking:
This tutorial is used to set up a project in Unity 2022.3.41f1 LTS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/1-1-introduction
So, the configuration is as follows for the camera:


VuforiaBehavior and DefaultInitializerErrorHandeler are added to the main camera as follows:

For the configuration of the Vuforia engine after pasting the license (Already created on the Vuforia website), the play mode changed to “SIMULATOR” as it is desired to use HoloLens:

An empty game object is added to the scene. Then an Image Target of the Vuforia engine is added to the scene:

A database is created on the Vuforia website and imported into the Unity project. Then “image target behavior” is configured to use that image as follows:

Node: On the Vuforia database the width of the image is set to 0.2 also.
A cube is created as the child of the ImageTarget and placed in the scene:

After running the app on the HoloLens in remoting mode I see the following:

Problem is that it doesn’t observe the physical image to put the sphere on it as expected:


Hi @MortezaNamvar, Vuforia does not support Holographic Remoting. Be aware that in SIMULATOR PlayMode, Vuforia does not use the camera feed and simulates the observations instead (you can read more about it here).
You can use WEBCAM mode to test detection and tracking in PlayMode, or you could capture a Vuforia Session Recording of what you want to test and use it in RECORDING mode, more on how to do that here.

If you want to scan any physical objects, you need to select WEBCAM mode in the Vuforia configuration to use the webcam on your PC or laptop. If you want to test Vuforia features on HoloLens, you could build and deploy your application to the HoloLens.
